# EF Core explicit ignore relation

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

```
public class Unit
{
   Public int Id { get; set; }
   Public virtual ICollection<Element> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; } 
}
```

We use a API call to get all `Element`s with related `Unit`s.
Like this:

```
Context.Elements.Include(o => o.Unit);
```

Our expectation was that only `Element`s would have a `Unit`. However the `Unit`s do also have `Element`s

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Unit": {
     "Id": 1,
     "Elements":[...]
  }
}
```

How do we exclude the `Element`s from `Unit.Elements`?

Comment: 1 Unit can have 0 or more Elements. But a Element must have a Unit to exist/to be created. You can't exclude the Elements from the Unit. That's how it works

Answer (score 2):

EF Core populate entity's navigation properties if related entities already loaded in the memory.

```
Context.Element.Include(e => e.Unit)
```

Line above will load all `Element` entities in the memory, so it will populate `Unit.Elements` as well.

> Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties
>   to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context
>   instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a
>   navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or
>   all of the related entities were previously loaded.

EF Core 2.1 now supports lazy loading which probably could answer your question, but, as I mentioned above, in your case all `Elements` already loaded in the memory.

[Loading Related Data - Lazing Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no solution for this.

As pointed out [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11564) there is a workaround available:

```
Context.Elements.Include(o => o.Unit).Select(o => new Element()
{
  Id = o.Id,
  Unit = o.Unit
});
```